# Wifi not working, BCM43142

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04, broadcom

For me, wifi had been working fine for quite sometime, but today I sent the laptop for repairs and since then the wifi does not work. This is probably not a hardware issue because ubuntu identifies my wifi card. Please find the relevant information below :

Output of lshw -C network

```
 *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 0c:84:dc:f9:12:af
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:16 memory:d1700000-d1707fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 0c
   serial: 78:84:3c:3c:8a:fe
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:30 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1500000-d1500fff memory:d1400000-d1403fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: usb0
   serial: 02:00:5a:54:63:33
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.192 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Output of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

What I've tried so far :

1. Restarting multiple times, cannot search any wifi networks
2. Reinstalled bcmwl-kernel-source, searched my wifi but could not connect.

EDIT : Adding output of rfkill list

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT 2 : Adding output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e071]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

UPDATE : 
Just discovered that I'm able to connect to mu android hotspot, but mot to my wifi.

Thanking you for any help in advance.

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 added `rfkill list` output

Comment: All looks OK. It must be a hardware issue, like not well attached antennas.

Comment: But then it should not have searched my wifi like it did once? Or maybe If it is a hardware issue I'll go back to the workshop, I just wanna be sure about it.

Comment: On the software side everything looks good.

Comment: Just in case add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`. I need a product ID.

Comment: Added, please check

Comment: It is OK. The  driver is correct.

Comment: Alright, thanks man, I'll get it checked tomorrow

Comment: @Pilot6 Well just found out that I'm able to connect to my android hotspot, any ideas?

Comment: So  it works. Check the other place you can't connect to.

Comment: My wifi is working in other laptop and mobiles, can't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it was an issue with the range of wifi. Got my adapter replaced and everything works fine now. Thank you all.